# Baixa resolução do texto no Python Kivy

Tags: python, python-kivy, resolução-de-tela, render

Estou iniciando no Python e Kivy, mas não estou compreendendo o porque da baixa resolução dos objetos gerados. Em uma simples tela de username e password, pode-se observar o texto serrilhado, ou seja, com baixa renderização.

Existe uma forma de conseguir uma qualidade melhor ou é uma limitação da linguagem?

[image: Print da tela]

Segue arquivos.

login.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Access(Widget):
    pass

class LoginApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Access()

LoginApp().run()
```

login.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<Access>:
    f_username: username
    f_password: password
    GridLayout:
        pos: root.center_x-self.width, root.center_y-self.height/2
        col_default_width: 100
        rows: 2
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: 'User Name:'
        TextInput:
            id: username
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: 'Password:'
        TextInput:
            id: password
            password: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que tenha ocorrido pela versão do seu kivy, ou devido a sua máquina, pois o kivy tem boost pela GPU, e pode ser usado para desenvolver games, então suporta resoluções mais altas.

O código que você está usando possui um exemplo na própria documentação do kivy, você pode olha-lá [aqui](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/kivy/latest/kivy.pdf), nas páginas 56 e 57, e as informações técnicas de gráficos e etc nas primeiras páginas.